# radio button to fil out a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, radio-button

hey there.
is there a way that if a user selects a radio button the rest of the form will fill out automatically?
most of the form is drop down menu's if that makes a difference.

thx

Comment: Can you give any more context to your question? In what environment have you created this form? What programming language are you using?

Comment: its all done using html css and javascript, its a custom computer builder where you select the components of the computer you would like and i want the radio buttons to create recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by making a function that fills out the form fields for you.  Then setting that function to the onclick of the radio button.  I have put together a quick and dirty example that does just this for you.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<script language="javascript">
function radioClick()
{
document.getElementById("txtField1").value = "Whatever you want!";
}
</script>


<body>

<input name="" type="radio" value="" onclick="radioClick()" />
<input id="txtField1"name="" type="text" />

</body>
</html>
```

Not working in Firefox! Just noticed that sorry, I'll figure it out in a sec!

Hey guys. Sorry I forgot that innerHtml was not supported by firefox.  You can simply switch it to .value and it works in both.

Comment: @ChrisBuckler: Could be, but tested with chrome,FF with local files and tested in jsfiddle too, none working, is this working for you: http://jsfiddle.net/TEaxF/

Comment: I think, the problem here is 'innerText'. Use the 'innerHTML' instead

Comment: @Trufa @Bharath Thanks for picking that out. Totally forgot innerHTML wasnt supported by Firefox. It should work now with .value. PS - I only tested in IE 6 and Firefox 3.6